# Can you install Office 2007 PIA's without office

Tags: .net, ms-office, office-interop, office-2007, office-pia

First of all, my question is not quite the same as

[Is Office 2007 PIA deployment possible without Office 2007?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370407/is-office-2007-pia-deployment-possible-without-office-2007)

I am not looking to use the PIA's yet. The IT engineers would ideally like to deploy the 2007 PIA's to everyone's computers before they upgrade Office 2007.  This way there is fewer things that have to go right all at once. I am wondering if this is possible

Comment: NOt programming related.

Comment: How is this not programming related? It's a deployment question about the .NET interop assemblies for PROGRAMMING against Office.  If nothing else, it a million times more programming related than "what is your favorite programming comic" or "What is the origin of your SO username?"

Comment: Actually @George this is completely programming related. If you don't understand VSTO questions please don't comment on them.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, we ended up doing it and it worked fine.

Comment: I don't think installing PIA without office would have any effect, the PIACheck does not return the component ID for Word, etc. Only basic components will be installed, like SmartTag.
So you need to install PIA again after Office is installed.

Comment: Check answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/370407/is-office-2007-pia-deployment-possible-without-office-2007 "PIA's can do nothing w/o Office." So, I think your answer is wrong.

Comment: @Priyank Bolia As mentioned in my question, I have already looked at that question.  My question is not "Will PIA work without Office?", it's "Can I install PIA, then install Office 07, and have it work?".  As mention, we ended up installing the PIA's before Office and it it currently working fine.  Given this fact, I am confused as to why you think I am wrong.

Comment: I don't know, but as I told in earlier post, installing PIA without installing Office had no effect for me. The PIACheck does not return the component ID for Word, which according to me, means that, the PIA is not installed properly.

Comment: I don't know what PIACheck is, but my experience agrees with that reported by Priyank. I ran o2007pia.msi, which is the MSI for Office 2007 PIAs, and I get no Office assemblies in the GAC. The MSI runs for about 5 seconds then quits with no message.

Comment: Uhm, would you care to add *how* you installed the 2007 PIAs?

Comment: According to answer here in the following link, it's not possible to install PIAs without Office installed. Please provide steps to install it without Office. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/92535871-c95b-4a50-af0d-d03ed61c956c/office-2010-pia-are-not-installed

Answer (score 1):

My best experience is deploing PIA with your application/add-in, because there are some awkward factors, which can be solved by this way.

If you will not register them to GAC, and tehy will stay in directory of you application/add-in you will not affect nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible. The Office PIA's require the correct version of Office to be installed first.

Comment: TcKs, can you please provide some reference?


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/370407/is-office-2007-pia-deployment-possible-without-office-2007/380148#380148

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/370407/is-office-2007-pia-deployment-possible-without-office-2007/380148#380148

Comment: You can deploy application with PIA and haven't office installed. Office capability can not be used of course, but if you install office later, it will run ok.

Comment: I just tried this with the Office 2007 PIAs saw the opposite of what @TcKs reports. I do not have Office 2007 installed. I ran o2007pia.msi, got a dialog that said "Please wait while Windows configures Office 2007 PIAs". In about 5 seconds the dialog disappears, and I could detect no change on the machine. I could not find any Office assemblies in the GAC. My experience agrees with @awaisj's response.

Comment: @TcKs Care to explain or perhaps provide some reference? I am trying to install MS Office 2007 PIA's and it won't let me w/o Office 2007 installed.

Comment: PIAs are only wrapper around Office COM+ libraries. PIA has NOT any Office functionality, it works only as bridge between C/C++ API of Office and .managed (.NET) code such as C# or VB.NET.