# Can I build a project referencing Office 2013 COM components without installing Office 2013?

Tags: c#, .net, office-interop

We have a small project that references Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word 8.6.0.0. The reference was added via the COM tab in the Add References window, so the underlying .csproj reference is a COMReference.

I'm trying to set up a build server at the moment, and according to [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21013912/can-i-still-use-microsoft-office-interop-assemblies-with-office-2013), it's no longer possible to work directly with Office 2013 PIAs.

This is incredibly frustrating as I don't want to have to deploy an instance of Office to my build server. Is there any way to achieve what I'm trying to do without installing Office?

Comment: Have you seen this? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee317478.aspx

Comment: They still exist, you can copy them out of GAC on a machine that has Office 2013 installed.  The Path property of the assembly references shows the paths of the files.  The wisdom of making the projects and the build *different* on the build server from the way they work on a dev's machine is a pretty low one.

Comment: @HansPassant fair point regarding build differences - I've updated the reference to point to a copy of the Interop DLL checked into our SCM so all machines will build from this copy. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: That's okayish.  But do write a big fat comment in a highly visible place in the source code, nobody is going to remember how to do this for Office 2020.