# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel missing in the Component Name list

Tags: c#, excel

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel in the Component Name list is missing on the Assemblies page.

I need to include that:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

But it throws error: *The type or namespace name 'Office' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)*

And I can't find it in References either.

Comment: Do you have installed the Office packet on your PC?

Comment: You mean the actual Microsoft Office Application? Yes I have, but why is that necessary to have installed MS Office in order to just write a C# console?

Comment: For using office interoop dll you need to have office install

Comment: I get for USING the program but why for just WRITING the code??

Comment: It is a PIA, they've been obsolete for the past 6 years already.  And no longer deployed since Office 2013.  Use the COM tab instead to add the reference, details [are here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21018418/17034).

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing interop package from microsoft depending on your version of excel.

Then check if the microsoft excel 12.0 library will be on your reference.

See if it helps.

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work. I tried installing both o2007pia and o2010pia and nothing happened..

Comment: Did you try looking at your visual studio if there are any references being added?

Comment: Try manually adding the reference to your visual studio. Locate the directory where your package is. Then look for microsoft office folders. I have not done it because installing / reinstalling interop package perfectly works for me.

Comment: But I can't get the actual file o2010pia.msi, I only managed to download the installer o2010pia and it doesn't work.. I don't know where I can download the actual o2010pia.msi

Comment: It is the actual installer, try opening it with other applications or if there are any files associated with it.

Comment: Ok, but I am trying to add it and it doesn't work. It says: A reference to 'C:\path\o2010pia.msi' could not be added. Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component.

Comment: It seems that the default extension to the reference is: .dll, .tlb, .olb, .ocx, .exe, .manifest

Comment: It sounds strange, msi are file extensions for microsoft installers. You just need to click it then it will automatically run.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know it was supposed to be in the COM tab, now I found it there. It works, tnx!

Answer (score 0):

On the Assemblies page, select Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel in the Component Name list. If you do not see the assemblies, you may need to ensure they are installed and displayed (see How to: Install Office Primary Interop Assemblies)
[https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kh3965hw.aspx][1]

Comment: Do I need to reinstall my whole MS Office??