# Primary interop assemblies for office 2010 not showing in prerequisite for VSTO Word add-in

Tags: c#, vsto, office-addins

I'm trying to deploy a **VSTO word add-in** application using Windows Installer. **prerequisite for setup project does not showing primary interop assemblies**.
I installed Microsoft office 2010 primary interop assemblies.

I'm working with VS2015 community , VSTO Word Add-in 2010 and MS Office 2010.

[Sample Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8niL.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21018418/17034

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I still use Microsoft.Office.Interop assemblies with office 2013?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21013912/can-i-still-use-microsoft-office-interop-assemblies-with-office-2013)