# microsoft.office.interop.powerpoint v16 (Office 365) with C#

Tags: c#, powerpoint, office365api

I've found a lot of references and examples using microsoft.office.interop.powerpoint using v12 through v15 (pre Office 365) but I cannot find any information on if it is possible to interact with PowerPoint from C# using version 16. From what I can tell Microsoft is no longer supporting this, but I'm wondering

I will say, I'm a novice at this, so I apologize is this is a silly question.

There are two things I'm trying to do:

1. **Save As** > *MP4*
2. Edit text on a slide

If you know, please let me know if this is even possible. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Can you include the links that you have found so far please? Good luck!

Comment: Hi Micky:
1. https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/docs. This doesn't seem to have interop capabilities
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49895408/cannot-add-reference-to-outlook-2016-office-365-interop-16-0-0-0. This seems to use v15 as a fallback, and I'm looking for something that uses v16.
3. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/ff762466(v=office.14). This uses v15 or earlier.

I'm starting to think it's not possible anymore, but not sure. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: All roads point to add-ins.  This isn't very fun for something like a bulk processing.  I saw something in PowerAutomate but that can become billable and ties you to O365 services.  There might be an LibreOffice/OpenOffice API?