# adding microsoft.office.interop.excel to visual studio 2015 does not work

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio

I currently making an inventory management system for thee company I am currently hired in. The system requires me to export data from `DataGridView` to Excel. I have tried clicking "Add Reference" to my references in solution explorer and selecting `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` but after I click OK it still is not in my references. I tried it in my code but then I get this error:

> Error CS0234 The type or namespace name 'Office' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21013912/17034

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not good to use this method. What if on somebody's computer there is not Excel?
Try open source lib as [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus) or as @Sagi mentioned Open XML

Answer (score 1):

There are other methods of generation Excel files from C# without using the ineterop.
One of the best ways is [Open XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh180830(v=office.14).aspx)