# Using Visual Basic in Visual Studio Community 2017 to Open a Microsoft Excel File

Tags: excel, vb.net, office-interop

In older versions of Visual Studio, writing VB code to access Microsoft Excel files required the namespace `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`. However, I can't find this namespace in the new version (15.8.7) of Visual Studio.

What code do I need to access Excel?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nothing has changed.  You can only use members of a namespace if you have referenced a library that contains members of that namespace.  Regardless of the VS version, you have to reference the Excel object library in order to use members of the specified namespace.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21018418/17034

Comment: Thanks, @jmcilhinney, for your reply. I've been looking for this DLL file, but I haven't had any luck. Do you know how where I should look to get it?

Thanks,

Comment: I found it buried in the depths of Visual Studio: [see this MSDN webpage](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/10d02d87-b3fa-4e9c-93ac-735446cedabb/where-is-microsoftofficeinteropexcel-dll-for-visual-studio-2017?forum=vsto)

Comment: It's exactly where it has always been.  Interestingly, I've installed Office 365 from the Microsoft Store and I don't see that library available.  Presumably you can/must use Office PIAs with Office apps from the Store.