# Folder GAC_MSIL in the assembly folder

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly, gac

I have a project C# it works stably on one of the computers under WinServer2012

I want to transfer the C # project to another computer under win10(64x)
there is a problem, the project does not work on win10 as it uses components Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.dll

I checked that on WinServer2012 the assembly folder contains the GAC_MSIL folder in which the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.dll library is located and the project uses it.

But the win10 (64x) GAC_MSIL folder is missing, and the assembly folder contains only a list of libraries.

I downloaded https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=3508 and installed the package but the GAC_MSIL folder did not appear.

Tell me what to install so that the GAC_MSIL folder appears in the assembly folder?

Comment: It is not missing.  Let's not guess where you looked, check [this Q+A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21013912/can-i-still-use-microsoft-office-interop-assemblies-with-office-2013) to see why you should no longer use the interop assembly.

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook/  ?

Comment: You referenced that DLL in your project ? You have the DLL with the rest of your application assembles/exe. Do you trust Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.dll will always be in the GAC ? (hint - your question). I dont know why not to provide it in the working directory of your application, and if exist in GAC, CLR will know where to load from.