# can't find a reference for Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access in visual studio 2017 C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to open a C# winforms VS 2015 project in VS 2017 and managed to get the right references for everything except for Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access. when i imported Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao I got  Errors for all my uses of this namespaces:

The type or namespace name 'Controls' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access'.

The type or namespace name ' AcFormOpenDataMode' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access'.

The type or namespace name ' AcView' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access'.

Comment: The Interop requires Microsoft Office to be installed and there is a different version of the Interop for each version of Office.  The Interop is very slow and converts the c# to a series of script language commands that Access recognizes.

Comment: what do you mean by installing Microsoft office?

Comment: And why does  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel work fine?

Comment: @Achinoam because you there is installed MS Excel and no installed MS Access?

Comment: @Achinoam, also, when installing this MS Office products, you must enable features called ".NET programming support" (or something like that).

Comment: @ vasily.sib thanks. you are right

Comment: @vasily.sib thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21013912/can-i-still-use-microsoft-office-interop-assemblies-with-office-2013