# Can a 'Post-policy reference' be removed from the application?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

The Fusion logs report a warning saying :

> WRN: Multiple versions of the same assembly were loaded into one context of an application domain:
>   WRN: Context: Default | Domain ID: 1 | Assembly Name: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c
>   WRN: Context: Default | Domain ID: 1 | Assembly Name: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c
>   WRN: This might lead to runtime failures.
>   WRN: It is recommended that you remove the dependency on multiple versions, and change the app.config file to point to the required version of the assembly only.*

Where as, i haven't referred the version 15.0.0.0 DLL anywhere. It automatically gets picked from the GAC. the log file further says:

> *LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
>   LOG: Post-policy reference: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c
>   LOG: Found assembly by looking in the GAC.
>   LOG: Binding succeeds. Returns assembly from C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access\15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.dll.
>   LOG: Assembly is loaded in default load context.*

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21018418/17034

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. How do you get the warning? And what do you want to do with these warnings?

Comment: I get the Warnings in the assembly binding logs. get these warnings when i run my application. I want to remove the redundant assembly reference which i'm not able to find.

Comment: What is your current project? can you give me a code example so that we could reproduce your problem?