# VS 2019 Community Excel interop in Microsoft 365

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

I used to interop with excel through C#. But after installed the latest version of Microsoft Office (now Microsoft 365) I got this error when I try to open excel:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast COM object of type
>   'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass' to interface type
>   'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application'. This operation failed
>   because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface
>   with IID '{000208D5-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}'

These are the references:

[image: References]

This is the path for Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel :

```
C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel\15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll
```

Can you help me to know, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Office 15.0 is Office 2013.  You are using 365.  You need to latest Interop that will work with 365.

Comment: Thanks @jdweng can you point me which interop is this one? I can't find anything in the web.

Comment: It may be on your computer already in the Program Files and you just need to change the version from 15.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/office-primary-interop-assemblies?view=vs-2019

Comment: Using the PIA is a practice that's been obsolete for [10 years already](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21018418/17034).  Looks like a WPF app, one way to get this exception is trying to run the interop code on a worker thread.  Hard to be sure when you don't post any repro code.

Comment: @carlosdelab, as usual, we use nuget package to use office excel api in c#. I suggest that you can install nuget package->Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel. Please try it and see if it works for you.